# Reference Request : Representation Theory Of Finite p-groups

Tags: reference-request, finite-groups, representation-theory, group-presentation, p-groups

In the (xi) group of the classification of groups of order $p^4$ given by W.Burnside in his book," Theory of Groups Of Finite Order". The group ($\mathbb{Z_{p^{2}}}\rtimes \mathbb{Z_{p^{}}}) \rtimes_{\phi}\mathbb{Z_{p^{}}} $, have presentation
$$<a,b,c : a^{p^{2}}=b^p=c^p=e, ab=ba^{1+p},ac=cab,bc=cb>$$

I was trying to explore about the representation(must be faithful) of the above group in $GL(4,F_p)$, i.e. group of $4\times 4$ invertible matrices , taken over $F_p$.  Please guide me in the right direction, from where to start or if my statement mathematically correct or not ?

Comment: You asked me for help in a comment in your question https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3738678/ and I spent some time working on it, but then you deleted the question. Why did you do that?

Comment: @DerekHolt Actually too many people reported that question to be incomplete and  that question was closed by the site. Due to anger, I removed my question just a few seconds later you posted your answer. I saw your answer after I deleted my post.Thanks and I am sorry for that. And I did as you suggested and get that (xi) group was [81,7], (xii) was [81,10] and (xiii) was [81,8]. Still I am unable to decode the . (dot) structure of [81,10]. Is it mean we can take either split or non split extension ?